# How to query elasticsearch based on response

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Im trying to query elasticsearch to do the following :

**Data going into Elastic**

```
Order Number    Product Name
order1          Chicken    
order2          Banana
order3          Chicken   
order1          Cucumber   
order2          Chicken
order3          Apples
order1          Flour
order2          Rice
order3          Nuts
```

This is the Query im using to get a Product Name

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
        "ProductName" : "Chicken"
}
```

Result : All orders that contain Chicken

```
    Order Number    Product Name
    order1          Chicken          
    order3          Chicken
    order2          Chicken
```

**What I would like to achieve:**
If the above orders have Chicken in it then give me all the other Products that was also purchased with Chicken.

```
Order Number    Product Name
order1          Cucumber
order2          Banana
order3          Apples
order1          Flour
order2          Rice
order3          Nuts
```

How do i go about constructing a query to do this ? please help i am very new to elasticsearch.

- Do I require to Run the first query get all orders that contain Chicken then extract the order numbers and run another query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has many different answers and it really comes down to what you want to do with this data beyond what you are asking.

Assuming however that all you want to do is get all orders that contain a particular product, I'd advise changing your indexing structure a bit.

You are indexing data in a very *SQL* like way. Instead you should be thinking in terms of documents or entities. As I see it an "order" should exist as a single document. It could look like this:

```
 "order": {
        "properties": {
         "orderNumber": {
           "type": "string"
          },
          "product": {

            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
                }
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

That is, a single order is a document, which can contain several products. This would allow you to get all orders which contain "Chicken" or whatever else, but would also allow you to get a list of all products by orderNumber.

Again this depends a lot of how you intend to use your data, the main thing I would keep in mind is that elasticsearch is not a relational database. You have to put a little more thought into how you store things as you can't do as complex joins when querying.

Comment: thank you for you response, i have restructured my data to contain all Product Names for a single order to be indexed in one document. This makes it so much simpler to query. Thank you